# Justify string algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

Just tanked a job interview where I was asked to implement a function with this signature:

```
function justify($str_in, $desired_length)
```

It needs to mimic what HTML's text-align: justify would do,  here's some examples (desired_length = 48)

```
    hello world there ok then                              = hello......world......there.......ok.......then
    hello                                                  = .....................hello.....................
    ok then                                                = ok.........................................then
    this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think = this.string.is.almost.certainly.longer.than.48.
    two words                                              = two.......................................words
    three ok words                                         = three.................ok..................words
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                                      = 1....2....3.....4.....5.....6.....7.....8.....9
```

(I replaced the spaces with periods to illustrate)

The length of spaces between words may never differ by more than one.

I *have* written a PHP solution, but I am more interested in what algorithms people can come up with to solve the problem. It was my first whiteboard question at a job interview ever, and I'm afraid a combination of factors made me take way longer than I should have.

Comment: people should pay close attention to the details of the space distribution in the `1____2____3_____4_____5_____6_____7_____8_____9` example(the extra spaces are centered).

Comment: @rambocoder I was thinking that as well, but it's not in the requirements here and adds complexity - unless it's implicit in the way HTML's justify works.

Comment: Actually... come to think of it, doesn't HTML's "justify" use kerning instead of spaces? :)

Comment: I just noticed that `hello______world______there_______ok_______then` isnt distrubted around the center, so I guess it's arbitrary.

Comment: HTML's justify won't center a single word. `Hello` and `two words` should be left aligned. no?

Comment: @sachleen: I'm not quite sure and can't be bothered to check, but for the purposes of this exercise they wanted `Hello` and `two words` to act as I've shown.

Comment: @Lyndsy: no, it doesn't have to be in PHP, I just chose to do it in PHP at the time, looking back on it I should have probably went with Python.

Comment: Since you didn't mention it here, I assume the input is "hello world there ok then hello ok then this string is almost..." and not an array of lines already divided, correct? The odd line separation you have chosen in your example suggests otherwise.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: the function only needs to handle 1 line at a time, those are just a series of test I ran on the function, the input will be "hello world there ok then" or "hello", and so on.

Comment: if the font is not monospace, you can't do this unless you have the width of each symbol. otherwise, count the symbols other than spaces, subtract from number of columns, divide that by word count minus 1, store each word in an array, print with for loop and put the amount of spaces you've calculated in between

Comment: @rambocoder They didn't really give me a time, but about 15 min into it they stopped me. I'm a little bitter about it because their lead programmer jumped in a few times and started trying to help me along, but while doing that kept getting his math wrong, and I just stood there in this high pressure situation looking at the wrong math (11*3=36 for example) and gathering the courage to speak up. He basically just confused me rather than helped me but that's life.

Comment: @yes123 - I'd rather not say, and yes, I am. :)

Comment: One strategy I've heard discussed is that interviewers don't actually *expect* you to finish a task like this within the time they set; part of what they're trying to see is how you deal with an impossible deadline, whether you churn out substandard code in order to meet it, etc.  I think it's an interesting strategy, but I certainly wouldn't use it as part of my hiring process.

Comment: @hakre - where in my question did I ask for the "shortest solution" or a solution at all? The question is asking for an algorithm to go about solving the problem. Naturally we are all programmers so people can't help writing solutions, but this wasn't a challenge or a competition in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: The example of the longer string is not clear. Why isn't it justified? Is it just cut and returned. Is it cut at the last whole non-space string and right-padded with spaces? It not only looks like that the decription was wrong (the HTML justify hint), it also looks like that the specification is imprecise. You probably should have never started to write a single line of code without clarifying the grey details. And give a hint on the company this starts to get funny.

Comment: @hakre - Again, not quite sure what you are saying, but the interviewer was not really that concerned about edge cases (a string longer than what we're justifying to) so I just asked if it was ok to truncate and he said that was fine. Also, the company is irrelevant and it is a private detail I don't care to get into. If you have so many problems with my question, just don't participate.

Comment: The problem is that the problem has not been precisely described. How would one know she is solving your problem, when the problem is not clear? So far we have seen that the hint on HTML justify **is wrong** and that other important infomration is missing. We only have some strings we could do a hashmap for to return that. If other input is passed, we can just throw an exception that for that input the output is unspecified. That's just not helpfull you ask that way!

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I came up with. I added the optional `$char` parameter so you can see what it's outputting - Of course you can pull it inside the function so the prototype matches the requirement.

```
function justify($str_in, $desired_length, $char = '_') {

    // Some common vars and simple error checking / sanitation
    $return = '';
    $str_in = trim( $str_in);
    $desired_length = intval( $desired_length);

    // If we've got invalid input, we're done
    if( $desired_length <= 0)
        return $str_in;

    // If the input string is greater than the length, we need to truncate it WITHOUT splitting words
    if( strlen( $str_in) > $desired_length) {
        $str = wordwrap($str_in, $desired_length);
        $str = explode("\n", $str);
        $str_in = $str[0];
    }

    $words = explode( ' ', $str_in);
    $num_words = count( $words);

    // If there's only one word, it's a simple edge case
    if( $num_words == 1) {
        $length = ($desired_length - strlen( $words[0])) / 2;
        $return .= str_repeat( $char, floor( $length)) . $words[0] . str_repeat( $char, ceil( $length));
    } else {
        $word_length = strlen( implode( '', $words));

        // Calculate the number of spaces to distribute over the words
        $num_words--; // We're going to eliminate the last word
        $spaces = floor( ($desired_length - $word_length) / $num_words);
        $remainder = $desired_length - $word_length - ($num_words * $spaces);

        $last = array_pop( $words);
        foreach( $words as $word) {
            // If we didn't get an even number of spaces to distribute, just tack it on to the front
            $spaces_to_add = $spaces;
            if( $remainder > 0) {
                $spaces_to_add++;
                $remainder--;
            }

            $return .= $word . str_repeat( $char, $spaces_to_add);
        }
        $return .= $last;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

And the test cases:

```
$inputs = array( 
    'hello world there ok then',
    'hello',
    'ok then',
    'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think',
    'two words',
    'three ok words',
    '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
);

foreach( $inputs as $x) {
    $ret = justify( $x, 48);
    echo 'Inp: ' . $x . " - strlen(" . strlen( $x) .  ")\n";
    echo 'Out: ' . $ret . " - strlen(" . strlen( $ret) .  ")\n\n";
}
```

And the output:

```
Inp: hello world there ok then - strlen(25)
Out: hello_______world_______there_______ok______then - strlen(48)

Inp: hello - strlen(5)
Out: _____________________hello______________________ - strlen(48)

Inp: ok then - strlen(7)
Out: ok__________________________________________then - strlen(48)

Inp: this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think - strlen(54)
Out: this_string_is_almost_certainly_longer_than_48_I - strlen(48)

Inp: two words - strlen(9)
Out: two________________________________________words - strlen(48)

Inp: three ok words - strlen(14)
Out: three__________________ok__________________words - strlen(48)

Inp: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - strlen(17)
Out: 1_____2_____3_____4_____5_____6_____7_____8____9 - strlen(48)
```

[And a demo!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/usNb72)

**Edit:** Cleaned up the code, and [it still works :)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xieUfk).

Comment: just a little remark concerning the `single word` case: aren't you centering it instead of justifying it? If I'm not wrong in a justified line the first word occupy the leftmost position, no matter if it's the only word of the line.

Comment: @nadirs - The test cases in the OP have that as the correct output - If it's not, then it's a very simple fix.

Answer (score 10):

Made it a personal challenge to not use any loops/recursion or regex with callbacks. I used a single `explode()` and a single `implode()` to achieve this. Great success!

## The Code

```
function justify($str, $maxlen) {
    $str = trim($str);

    $strlen = strlen($str);
    if ($strlen >= $maxlen) {
        $str = wordwrap($str, $maxlen);
        $str = explode("\n", $str);
        $str = $str[0];
        $strlen = strlen($str);
    }

    $space_count = substr_count($str, ' ');
    if ($space_count === 0) {
        return str_pad($str, $maxlen, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
    }

    $extra_spaces_needed = $maxlen - $strlen;
    $total_spaces = $extra_spaces_needed + $space_count;

    $space_string_avg_length = $total_spaces / $space_count;
    $short_string_multiplier = floor($space_string_avg_length);
    $long_string_multiplier = ceil($space_string_avg_length);

    $short_fill_string = str_repeat(' ', $short_string_multiplier);
    $long_fill_string = str_repeat(' ', $long_string_multiplier);

    $limit = ($space_string_avg_length - $short_string_multiplier) * $space_count;

    $words_split_by_long = explode(' ', $str, $limit+1);
    $words_split_by_short = $words_split_by_long[$limit];
    $words_split_by_short = str_replace(' ', $short_fill_string, $words_split_by_short);
    $words_split_by_long[$limit] = $words_split_by_short;

    $result = implode($long_fill_string, $words_split_by_long);

    return $result;
}
```

## Short (348 chars)

```
function j($s,$m){$s=trim($s);$l=strlen($s);if($l>=$m){$s=explode("\n",wordwrap($s,$m));$s=$s[0];$l=strlen($s);}$c=substr_count($s,' ');if($c===0)return str_pad($s,$m,' ',STR_PAD_BOTH);$a=($m-$l+$c)/$c;$h=floor($a);$i=($a-$h)*$c;$w=explode(' ',$s,$i+1);$w[$i]=str_replace(' ',str_repeat(' ',$h),$w[$i]);return implode(str_repeat(' ',ceil($a)),$w);}
```

## Algorithm / Code explanation

1. Handle the two exceptions (string longer than max length or only one word).
2. Find the average space needed between each word (`$space_string_avg_length`).
3. Create a long and short fill string for use between the words, based on `ceil()` and `floor()` of the `$space_string_avg_length`, respectively.
4. Find out how many long fill strings we need. (`$limit+1`).
5. Split the text based on how many long fill strings we need.
6. Replace spaces in the last part of the array, made by the split, with the short fill strings.
7. Join the split text back together with the long fill strings.

## Testing

```
$tests = array(
    'hello world there ok then',
    'hello',
    'ok then',
    'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think',
    'two words',
    'three ok words',
    '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
);

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $len_before = strlen($test);
    $processed = str_replace(' ', '_', justify($test, 48));
    $len_after = strlen($processed);
    echo "IN($len_before): $test\n";
    echo "OUT($len_after): $processed\n";
}
```

## Results

```
IN(25): hello world there ok then
OUT(48): hello_______world_______there_______ok______then
IN(5): hello
OUT(48): _____________________hello______________________
IN(7): ok then
OUT(48): ok__________________________________________then
IN(54): this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think
OUT(48): this_string_is_almost_certainly_longer_than_48_I
IN(9): two words
OUT(48): two________________________________________words
IN(14): three ok words
OUT(48): three__________________ok__________________words
IN(17): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
OUT(48): 1_____2_____3_____4_____5_____6_____7_____8____9
```

## [See it run!](http://codepad.org/rgM2q2jT)

Comment: This has the downside of breaking words when truncating long strings. [See this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hQbPof).

Comment: @nickb: That's a great point! [Updated my algorithm](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UljN7N) to correct this. Also updated the benchmarks, it took a slight performance hit.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my solution with no pesky loops

```
function justify( $str_in, $desired_length=48 ) {
    if ( strlen( $str_in ) > $desired_length ) {
        $str_in = current( explode( "\n", wordwrap( $str_in, $desired_length ) ) );
    }
    $string_length = strlen( $str_in );
    $spaces_count = substr_count( $str_in, ' ' );
    $needed_spaces_count = $desired_length - $string_length + $spaces_count;
    if ( $spaces_count === 0 ) {
        return str_pad( $str_in, $desired_length, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH );
    }
    $spaces_per_space = ceil( $needed_spaces_count / $spaces_count );
    $spaced_string = preg_replace( '~\s+~', str_repeat( ' ', $spaces_per_space ), $str_in );
    return preg_replace_callback(
        sprintf( '~\s{%s}~', $spaces_per_space ),
        function ( $m ) use( $spaces_per_space ) {
            return str_repeat( ' ', $spaces_per_space-1 );
        },
        $spaced_string,
        strlen( $spaced_string ) - $desired_length
    );
}
```

Comments and output...

https://gist.github.com/2939068

1. Find out how many spaces there are
2. Find out how many spaces are needed
3. Replace existing spaces with the amount of spaces (evenly distributed) needed to meet or just exceed desired line length
4. Use preg_replace_callback to replace the amount of `\s{spaces_inserted}` with `\s{spaces_inserted-1}` necessary to meet the desired line length

Comment: Very nice.  Only flaw was the too-long line.

Comment: @ghoti - yeah long lines have been fixed

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` still uses a loop construct internally, so it's just an implicit rather than an explicit loop.

Comment: @ken - right, but the pitfalls that come with using loops don't apply

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to see which algorithm was the most efficient, so I ran some benchmarks. I did 100k iterations of all 7 test cases. (Ran it in a single core Ubuntu VM)

The results of *@ppsreejith* and *@Kristian Antonsen*'s code are omitted, because their code crashed when I tried to run it. <del>*@PhpMyCoder*'s code ran as long as I didn't do the formatting to 48 length after object construction. Therefore the test result is incomplete.</del> (Fixed)

## Benchmark results

```
$ php justify.bench.php
Galen(justify1): 5.1464750766754
nickb(justify2): 3.8629620075226
Paolo Bergantino(justify3): 4.3705048561096
user381521(justify5): 8.5988481044769
vlzvl(justify7): 6.6795041561127
Alexander(justify8): 6.7060301303864
ohaal(justify9): 2.9896130561829

PhpMyCoder: 6.1514630317688 (Fixed!)
```

## justify.bench.php

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    'hello world there ok then',
    'hello',
    'ok then',
    'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think',
    'two words',
    'three ok words',
    '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
);
$testers = array(
    'Galen' => 'justify1',
    'nickb' => 'justify2',
    'Paolo Bergantino' => 'justify3',
//    'Kristian Antonsen' => 'justify4',
    'user381521' => 'justify5',
//    'ppsreejith' => 'justify6',
    'vlzvl' => 'justify7',
    'Alexander' => 'justify8',
    'ohaal' => 'justify9'
);
// ppsreejith and Kristian Antonsen's code crashed and burned when I tried to run it
// PhpMyCoder is a special case, but his code also crashed when doing $jus->format(48);

foreach ($testers as $tester => $func) {
    $b=microtime(true);
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++)
        foreach ($tests as $test)
            $func($test,48);
    $a=microtime(true);
    echo $tester.'('.$func.'): '.($a-$b)."\n";
}

echo "\n";

// Fixed!
$jus = new Justifier($tests);
$b=microtime(true);

for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    $jus->format(54);
}

$a=microtime(true);
echo 'PhpMyCoder: '.($a-$b)." (Fixed!)\n";

// ALGORITHMS BELOW

// Galen
function justify1( $str_in, $desired_length=48 ) {
    if ( strlen( $str_in ) > $desired_length ) {
        $str_in = current( explode( "\n", wordwrap( $str_in, $desired_length ) ) );
    }
    $string_length = strlen( $str_in );
    $spaces_count = substr_count( $str_in, ' ' );
    $needed_spaces_count = $desired_length - $string_length + $spaces_count;
    if ( $spaces_count === 0 ) {
        return str_pad( $str_in, $desired_length, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH );
    }
    $spaces_per_space = ceil( $needed_spaces_count / $spaces_count );
    $spaced_string = preg_replace( '~\s+~', str_repeat( ' ', $spaces_per_space ), $str_in );
    return preg_replace_callback(
        sprintf( '~\s{%s}~', $spaces_per_space ),
        function ( $m ) use( $spaces_per_space ) {
            return str_repeat( ' ', $spaces_per_space-1 );
        },
        $spaced_string,
        strlen( $spaced_string ) - $desired_length
    );
}
// nickb
function justify2($str_in, $desired_length, $char = '_') {

    // Some common vars and simple error checking / sanitation
    $return = '';
    $str_in = trim( $str_in);
    $desired_length = intval( $desired_length);

    // If we've got invalid input, we're done
    if( $desired_length <= 0)
        return $str_in;

    // If the input string is greater than the length, we need to truncate it WITHOUT splitting words
    if( strlen( $str_in) > $desired_length) {
        $str = wordwrap($str_in, $desired_length);
        $str = explode("\n", $str);
        $str_in = $str[0];
    }

    $words = explode( ' ', $str_in);
    $num_words = count( $words);

    // If there's only one word, it's a simple edge case
    if( $num_words == 1) {
        $length = ($desired_length - strlen( $words[0])) / 2;
        $return .= str_repeat( $char, floor( $length)) . $words[0] . str_repeat( $char, ceil( $length));
    } else {
        $word_length = strlen( implode( '', $words));

        // Calculate the number of spaces to distribute over the words
        $num_words--; // We're going to eliminate the last word
        $spaces = floor( ($desired_length - $word_length) / $num_words);
        $remainder = $desired_length - $word_length - ($num_words * $spaces);

        $last = array_pop( $words);
        foreach( $words as $word) {
            // If we didn't get an even number of spaces to distribute, just tack it on to the front
            $spaces_to_add = $spaces;
            if( $remainder > 0) {
                $spaces_to_add++;
                $remainder--;
            }

            $return .= $word . str_repeat( $char, $spaces_to_add);
        }
        $return .= $last;
    }
    return $return;
}
// Paolo Bergantino
function justify3($str, $to_len) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $strlen = strlen($str);

    if($str == '') return '';

    if($strlen >= $to_len) {
        return substr($str, 0, $to_len);   
    }

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $word_count = count($words);
    $space_count = $word_count - 1;

    if($word_count == 1) {
        return str_pad($str, $to_len, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
    }

    $space = $to_len - $strlen + $space_count;
    $per_space = $space/$space_count;

    if(is_int($per_space)) {
        return implode($words, str_pad('', $per_space, ' '));    
    }

    $new_str = '';
    $spacing = floor($per_space);
    $new_str .= $words[0] . str_pad('', $spacing);
    foreach($words as $x => $word) {
        if($x == $word_count - 1 || $x == 0) continue;
        if($x < $word_count - 1) {
            $diff = $to_len - strlen($new_str) - (strlen(implode('', array_slice($words, $x))));
            $new_str .= $word . str_pad('', floor($diff/($space_count - $x)), ' ');
        }
    }
    $new_str .= $words[$x];

    return $new_str;   
}
// Kristian Antonsen
function justify4($str_in, $desired_length)
{
    foreach ($str_in as &$line) {
        $words = explode(' ', $line);
        $word_count = count($words) - 1;
        $spaces_to_fill = $desired_length - strlen($line) + $word_count;
        if (count($words) == 1) {
            $line = str_repeat('_', ceil($spaces_to_fill/2)) . $line
                  . str_repeat('_', floor($spaces_to_fill/2));
            continue;
        }
        $next_space = floor($spaces_to_fill/$word_count);
        $leftover_space = $spaces_to_fill % $word_count;
        $line = array_shift($words);
        foreach($words as $word) {
            $extra_space = ($leftover_space) ? ceil($leftover_space / $word_count) : 0;
            $leftover_space -= $extra_space;
            $line .= str_repeat('_', $next_space + $extra_space) . $word;
        }
    }
    return $str_in;
}
// user381521
function justify5 ($str, $len)
{
    // split by whitespace, remove empty strings
    $words = array_diff (preg_split ('/\s+/', $str), array (""));

    // just space if no words
    if (count ($words) == 0)
        return str_repeat (" ", $len);

    // add empty strings if only one element
    if (count ($words) == 1)
        $words = array ("", $words[0], "");

    // get number of words and spaces
    $wordcount = count ($words);
    $numspaces = $wordcount - 1;

    // get number of non-space characters
    $numchars = array_sum (array_map ("strlen", $words));

    // get number of characters remaining for space
    $remaining = $len - $numchars;

    // return if too little spaces remaining
    if ($remaining <= $numspaces)
        return substr (implode (" ", $words), 0, $len);

    // get number of spaces per space
    $spaces_per_space = $remaining / $numspaces;
    $spaces_leftover = $remaining % $numspaces;

    // make array for spaces, spread out leftover spaces
    $spaces = array_fill (0, $numspaces, $spaces_per_space);
    while ($spaces_leftover--)
        $spaces[$numspaces - $spaces_leftover - 1]++;
    $spaces[] = 0; // make count ($words) == count ($spaces)

    // join it all together
    $result = array ();
    foreach ($words as $k => $v)
        array_push ($result, $v, str_repeat (" ", $spaces[$k]));
    return implode ($result);
}
// ppsreejith
function justify6($str, $to_len) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $strlen = strlen($str);

    if($str == '') return '';

    if($strlen >= $to_len) {
        return substr($str, 0, $to_len);   
    }

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $word_count = count($words);
    $space_count = $word_count - 1;

    if($word_count == 1) {
        return str_pad($str, $to_len, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
    }

    $space = $to_len - $strlen + $space_count;
    $per_space = floor($space/$space_count);
    $spaces = str_pad('', $per_space, ' ');
    $curr_word = implode($words, $spaces);
    while(strlen($curr_word) < $to_len){
    $curr_word = substr($curr_word,0,preg_match("[! ][".$spaces."][! ]",$curr_word)." ".preg_match("[! ][".$spaces."][! ]",$curr_word));
    }
    return $curr_word;
}
// vlzvl
function justify7($str_in, $desired_length)
{
   $str_in = preg_replace("!\s+!"," ",$str_in);   // get rid of multiple spaces
   $words = explode(" ",$str_in);   // break words
   $num_words = sizeof($words);     // num words
   if ($num_words==1) {
      return str_pad($str_in,$desired_length,"_",STR_PAD_BOTH);
   }
   else {
      $num_chars = 0; $lenwords = array();
      for($x=0;$x<$num_words;$x++) { $num_chars += $lenwords[$x] = strlen($words[$x]); }
      $each_div = round(($desired_length - $num_chars) / ($num_words-1));
      for($x=0,$sum=0;$x<$num_words;$x++) { $sum += ($lenwords[$x] + ($x<$num_words-1 ? $each_div : 0)); }
      $space_to_addcut = ($desired_length - $sum);
      for($x=0;$x<$num_words-1;$x++) {
         $words[$x] .= str_repeat("_",$each_div+($each_div>1? ($space_to_addcut<0?-1:($space_to_addcut>0?1:0)) :0));
         if ($each_div>1) { $space_to_addcut += ($space_to_addcut<0 ? 1 : ($space_to_addcut>0?-1:0) ); }
      }
      return substr(implode($words),0,$desired_length);
   }
}
// Alexander
function justify8($str, $length) {
  $words   = explode(' ', $str);
  if(count($words)==1) $words = array("", $str, "");
  $spaces  = $length - array_sum(array_map("strlen", $words));
  $add     = (int)($spaces / (count($words) - 1));
  $left    = $spaces % (count($words) - 1);
  $spaced  = implode(str_repeat("_", $add + 1), array_slice($words, 0, $left + 1));
  $spaced .= str_repeat("_", max(1, $add));
  $spaced .= implode(str_repeat("_", max(1, $add)), array_slice($words, $left + 1));
  return substr($spaced, 0, $length);
}
// ohaal
function justify9($s,$m){$s=trim($s);$l=strlen($s);if($l>=$m){$s=explode("\n",wordwrap($s,$m));$s=$s[0];$l=strlen($s);}$c=substr_count($s,' ');if($c===0)return str_pad($s,$m,' ',STR_PAD_BOTH);$a=($m-$l+$c)/$c;$h=floor($a);$i=($a-$h)*$c;$w=explode(' ',$s,$i+1);$w[$i]=str_replace(' ',str_repeat(' ',$h),$w[$i]);return implode(str_repeat(' ',ceil($a)),$w);}


// PhpMyCoder
class Justifier {
    private $text;

    public function __construct($text) {
        if(!is_string($text) && !is_array($text)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected a string or an array of strings, instead received type: ' . gettype($text));
        }

        if(is_array($text)) {
            // String arrays must be converted to JustifierLine arrays
            $this->text = array_map(function($line) {
                return JustifierLine::fromText($line);
            }, $text);
        } else {
            // Single line of text input
            $this->text = $text;
        }
    }

    public function format($width = NULL) {
        // Strings have to be broken into an array and then jusitifed
        if(is_string($this->text)) {
            if($width == null) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('A width must be provided for separation when an un-split string is provided');
            }

            if($width <= 0) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected a positive, non-zero width, instead received width of ' . $width);
            }

            // Break up a JustifierLine of all text until each piece is smaller or equal to $width
            $lines = array(JustifierLine::fromText($this->text));
            $count = 0;
            $newLine = $lines[0]->breakAtColumn($width);

            while($newLine !== null) {
                $lines[] = $newLine;
                $newLine = $lines[++$count]->breakAtColumn($width);
            }
        } else {
            $lines = $this->text;

            // Allow for fluid width (uses longest line with single space)
            if($width == NULL) {
                $width = -1;

                foreach($lines as $line) {
                    // Width of line = Sum of the lengths of the words and the spaces (number of words - 1)
                    $newWidth = $line->calculateWordsLength() + $line->countWords() - 1;

                    if($newWidth > $width) { // Looking for the longest line
                        $width = $newWidth;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Justify each element of array
        //$output = array_map(function($line) use ($width) {
        //    return $this->justify($line, $width);
        //}, $lines);

        $output = array();
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            $output[] = $this->justify($line, $width);
        }            

        // If a single-line is passed in, a single line is returned
        if(count($output)) {
            return $output[0];
        }

        return $output;
    }

    private function justify(JustifierLine $line, $width) {
        // Retrieve already calculated line information
        $words     = $line->extractWords();
        $spaces    = $line->countWords() - 1;
        $wordLens  = $line->findWordLengths();
        $wordsLen  = $line->calculateWordsLength();
        $minWidth  = $wordsLen + $spaces;
        $output    = '';

        if($minWidth > $width) {
            throw new LengthException('A minimum width of ' . $minWidth . ' was required, but a width of ' . $width . ' was given instead');
        }

        // No spaces means only one word (center align)
        if($spaces == 0) {
            return str_pad($words[0], $width, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
        }

        for(;$spaces > 0; $spaces--) {
            // Add next word to output and subtract its length from counters
            $output   .= array_shift($words);
            $length    = array_shift($wordLens);
            $wordsLen -= $length;
            $width    -= $length;

            if($spaces == 1) { // Last Iteration
                return $output . str_repeat(' ', $width - $wordsLen) . $words[0];
            }

            // Magic padding is really just simple math
            $padding  = floor(($width - $wordsLen) / $spaces);
            $output  .= str_repeat(' ', $padding);
            $width   -= $padding;
        }
    }
}

class JustifierLine {
    private $words;
    private $numWords;
    private $wordLengths;
    private $wordsLength;

    public static function fromText($text) {
        // Split words into an array
        preg_match_all('/[^ ]+/', $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $words       = $matches[0];

        // Count words
        $numWords    = count($words);

        // Find the length of each word
        $wordLengths = array_map('strlen', $words);

        //And Finally, calculate the total length of all words
        $wordsLength = array_reduce($wordLengths, function($result, $length) {
            return $result + $length;
        }, 0);

        return new JustifierLine($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength);
    }

    private function __construct($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength) {
        $this->words       = $words;
        $this->numWords    = $numWords;
        $this->wordLengths = $wordLengths;
        $this->wordsLength = $wordsLength;
    }

    public function extractWords() { return $this->words; }
    public function countWords() { return $this->numWords; }
    public function findWordLengths() { return $this->wordLengths; }
    public function calculateWordsLength() { return $this->wordsLength; }

    public function breakAtColumn($column) {
        // Avoid extraneous processing if we can determine no breaking can be done
        if($column >= ($this->wordsLength + $this->numWords - 1)) {
            return null;
        }

        $width       = 0;
        $wordsLength = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numWords; $i++) {
            // Add width of next word
            $width += $this->wordLengths[$i];

            // If the line is overflowing past required $width
            if($width > $column) {
                // Remove overflow at end & create a new object with the overflow
                $words             = array_splice($this->words, $i);
                $numWords          = $this->numWords - $i;
                $this->numWords    = $i;
                $wordLengths       = array_splice($this->wordLengths, $i);
                $tempWordsLength   = $wordsLength;
                $wordsLength       = $this->wordsLength - $wordsLength;
                $this->wordsLength = $tempWordsLength;

                return new JustifierLine($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength);
            }

            $width++; // Assuming smallest spacing to fit

            // We also have to keep track of the total $wordsLength
            $wordsLength += $this->wordLengths[$i];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, my code did much better than I expected. Cool numbers, thanks!

Comment: At the end of the day if Code A takes .1 seconds to run and Code B takes .2 seconds to run but Code A is a jumbled mess, go with Code B

Comment: if you have some time update my version with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058483/justify-string-algorithm/11059127#11059127) and do some benchmark; im just curious and because that benchmark woke something in me :) tx

Comment: @vlzvl: Done. If you make any more changes to your algorithm, feel free to update my answer with the benchmarks yourself. :)

Comment: Did you run my bit on PHP 5.4? I just notice when doing some profiling of my own on XDebug that PHP 5.3 doesn't support my code because I use `$this` in a callback.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Your suspicions are correct! `PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)`. Didn't think to check the PHP version, heh, good catch!

Comment: I just realized why mine crashes. You give my formatter an array, but one of the elements in that array (`this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think`) is longer than the 48 characters you tell it to format to. If you call `$this->format()` or give it an explicit length (`$this->format(54)`) it won't throw a `LengthException`. (And I updated the code in my post to support PHP 5.3)

Comment: Here's a working test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/K7Lurn

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution. No pesky regular expressions :)

```
function justify($str, $length) {
  $words   = explode(' ', $str);
  if(count($words)==1) $words = array("", $str, "");
  $spaces  = $length - array_sum(array_map("strlen", $words));
  $add     = (int)($spaces / (count($words) - 1));
  $left    = $spaces % (count($words) - 1);
  $spaced  = implode(str_repeat("_", $add + 1), array_slice($words, 0, $left + 1));
  $spaced .= str_repeat("_", max(1, $add));
  $spaced .= implode(str_repeat("_", max(1, $add)), array_slice($words, $left + 1));
  return substr($spaced, 0, $length);
}
```

This is powered by [PHP array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Here is the [working example](http://codepad.org/UXD2OECf).

Answer (score 3):

Just so no one thinks I'm trying to have them do my homework for me, this is my (working, I think) solution.

I'm not sure I could have possibly been expected to write this much code on a whiteboard on demand, however, so I'm mostly curious to see how others would tackle it without looking at my code. (I made it to around the foreach in the interview before they called 'time' on me, so to speak)

```
function justify($str, $to_len) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $strlen = strlen($str);

    if($str == '') return '';

    if($strlen >= $to_len) {
        return substr($str, 0, $to_len);   
    }

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $word_count = count($words);
    $space_count = $word_count - 1;

    if($word_count == 1) {
        return str_pad($str, $to_len, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
    }

    $space = $to_len - $strlen + $space_count;
    $per_space = $space/$space_count;

    if(is_int($per_space)) {
        return implode($words, str_pad('', $per_space, ' '));    
    }

    $new_str = '';
    $spacing = floor($per_space);
    $new_str .= $words[0] . str_pad('', $spacing);
    foreach($words as $x => $word) {
        if($x == $word_count - 1 || $x == 0) continue;
        if($x < $word_count - 1) {
            $diff = $to_len - strlen($new_str) - (strlen(implode('', array_slice($words, $x))));
            $new_str .= $word . str_pad('', floor($diff/($space_count - $x)), ' ');
        }
    }
    $new_str .= $words[$x];

    return $new_str;   
}

$tests = array(' hello world there ok then ', 'hello', 'ok then', 'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think', 'two words', 'three ok words', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9');

foreach($tests as $word) {
    print $word . ' = ' . str_replace(' ', '_', justify($word, 48)) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I miss my list comprehensions in Python ...

```
<?php
function justify ($str, $len)
{
    // split by whitespace, remove empty strings
    $words = array_diff (preg_split ('/\s+/', $str), array (""));

    // just space if no words
    if (count ($words) == 0)
        return str_repeat (" ", $len);

    // add empty strings if only one element
    if (count ($words) == 1)
        $words = array ("", $words[0], "");

    // get number of words and spaces
    $wordcount = count ($words);
    $numspaces = $wordcount - 1;

    // get number of non-space characters
    $numchars = array_sum (array_map ("strlen", $words));

    // get number of characters remaining for space
    $remaining = $len - $numchars;

    // return if too little spaces remaining
    if ($remaining <= $numspaces)
        return substr (implode (" ", $words), 0, $len);

    // get number of spaces per space
    $spaces_per_space = $remaining / $numspaces;
    $spaces_leftover = $remaining % $numspaces;

    // make array for spaces, spread out leftover spaces
    $spaces = array_fill (0, $numspaces, $spaces_per_space);
    while ($spaces_leftover--)
        $spaces[$numspaces - $spaces_leftover - 1]++;
    $spaces[] = 0; // make count ($words) == count ($spaces)

    // join it all together
    $result = array ();
    foreach ($words as $k => $v)
        array_push ($result, $v, str_repeat (" ", $spaces[$k]));
    return implode ($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt.

```
function justify($str_in, $desired_length)
{
    foreach ($str_in as &$line) {
        $words = explode(' ', $line);
        $word_count = count($words) - 1;
        $spaces_to_fill = $desired_length - strlen($line) + $word_count;
        if (count($words) == 1) {
            $line = str_repeat('_', ceil($spaces_to_fill/2)) . $line
                  . str_repeat('_', floor($spaces_to_fill/2));
            continue;
        }
        $next_space = floor($spaces_to_fill/$word_count);
        $leftover_space = $spaces_to_fill % $word_count;
        $line = array_shift($words);
        foreach($words as $word) {
            $extra_space = ($leftover_space) ? ceil($leftover_space / $word_count) : 0;
            $leftover_space -= $extra_space;
            $line .= str_repeat('_', $next_space + $extra_space) . $word;
        }
    }
    return $str_in;
}
```

I've tried to keep it relatively concise, which has impacted the readability. But here's how it works:

For each entry, we split up the words into an array `$words`. Because we might want spaces before and after the word, we also add an empty string to the beginning and ending of the array.

We calculate the left-over amount of spaces `$leftover_space` (that is, the spaces we need to insert somewhere), and divide it by number of words `$word_count`, so we know the average of how many spaces to put in between each word.

Whenever we add a word, we also add a few spaces `$extra_space`, depending on how many are left. After that, we remove the amount added from the `$leftover_space`.

#### Sample output

```
$data = justify($data, 48);
print_r($data);

Array
(
    [0] => 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
    [1] => hello_______world_______there_______ok______then
    [2] => ______________________hello_____________________
    [3] => ok__________________________________________then
    [4] => this__string__is_almost_certainly_longer_than_48
    [5] => two________________________________________words
    [6] => three__________________ok__________________words
    [7] => 1_____2_____3_____4_____5_____6_____7_____8____9
)
```

Comment: I just get a bunch of warnings

Comment: It doesn't exactly **justify**, does it?

Comment: @ghoti You're right. I don't know what I was thinking. Now it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will fail for strings larger than 48 characters with the desired length set to 48.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is fully working: (the "_" is just keeping the space visible)

```
function justify($str_in, $desired_length)
{
   $str_in = preg_replace("!\s+!"," ",$str_in);   // get rid of multiple spaces
   $words = explode(" ",$str_in);   // break words
   $num_words = sizeof($words);     // num words   
   if ($num_words==1) {   
      return str_pad($str_in,$desired_length,"_",STR_PAD_BOTH);   
   }
   else {
      $num_chars = 0; $lenwords = array();
      for($x=0;$x<$num_words;$x++) { $num_chars += $lenwords[$x] = strlen($words[$x]); }
      $each_div = round(($desired_length - $num_chars) / ($num_words-1));
      for($x=0,$sum=0;$x<$num_words;$x++) { $sum += ($lenwords[$x] + ($x<$num_words-1 ? $each_div : 0)); }
      $space_to_addcut = ($desired_length - $sum);
      for($x=0;$x<$num_words-1;$x++) {
         $words[$x] .= str_repeat("_",$each_div+($each_div>1? ($space_to_addcut<0?-1:($space_to_addcut>0?1:0)) :0));
         if ($each_div>1) { $space_to_addcut += ($space_to_addcut<0 ? 1 : ($space_to_addcut>0?-1:0) ); } 
      }
      return substr(implode($words),0,$desired_length);
   }
}
```

**EDITED:**

Function now get rid of multiple spaces between words as well.
How it works (*in short*):

- removes continuous spaces between words
- count words so if one (the *'hello'* example) just padding both and echo it.
- ..otherwise count the characters of the used words
- calculate the global and partial space to add (the **'_'** in example).
- calculate the extra space to add (string len < desired) OR remove (string len > desired) and apply it to padding.
- final, reduce the final string to desired length.

**TESTING:**

```
$tests = array(
   'hello world there ok then',
   'hello',
   'ok then',
   'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think',
   'three ok words',
   '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9',
   'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text'
);

$arr = array();
foreach($tests as $key=>$val) {
   $arr[$key] = justify($val,50);
   $arr[$key] .= " - (chars: ".strlen($arr[$key]).")";
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($arr,TRUE)."</pre>";
```

**AND THE RESULT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello________world_______there_______ok_______then - (chars: 50)
    [1] => ______________________hello_______________________ - (chars: 50)
    [2] => ok____________________________________________then - (chars: 50)
    [3] => this_string_is_almost_certainly_longer_than_48_I_t - (chars: 50)
    [4] => three___________________ok___________________words - (chars: 50)
    [5] => 1______2_____3_____4_____5_____6_____7_____8_____9 - (chars: 50)
    [6] => Lorem____Ipsum____is_____simply_____dummy_____text - (chars: 50)
)
```

**THAT WAS TOUGH :)**

**EDITED 2:**

Function is now about ***20% faster***, because that benchmark touched me :)

Answer (score 2):

## The (Semi-Long) Solution

It's taken me a while to perfect (probably much, much longer than an interviewer would have allowed for), but I've come up with an elegant, 162 line OOP solution to this problem. I included functionality to allow for the justifying of a single string, array of strings (already separated into lines) or a long string that needs to be broken up into lines of a maximum width first. Demos follow the code block.

<del>**Important Note:** This class will only work in PHP 5.4. I realized this when running a version on my own server PHP (5.3.6) to get profiling stats with XDebug. PHP 5.3 complains about my use of `$this` in the anonymous function. A quick check of the [docs on anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) reveals that `$this` could not be used in the context of an anonymous function until 5.4. If anyone can find a clean workaround to this, please drop it in the comments.</del> **Added support for PHP 5.3!**

```
<?php
class Justifier {
    private $text;

    public function __construct($text) {
        if(!is_string($text) && !is_array($text)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected a string or an array of strings, instead received type: ' . gettype($text));
        }

        if(is_array($text)) {
            // String arrays must be converted to JustifierLine arrays
            $this->text = array_map(function($line) {
                return JustifierLine::fromText($line);
            }, $text);
        } else {
            // Single line of text input
            $this->text = $text;
        }
    }

    public function format($width = null) {
        // Strings have to be broken into an array and then jusitifed
        if(is_string($this->text)) {
            if($width == null) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('A width must be provided for separation when an un-split string is provided');
            }

            if($width <= 0) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected a positive, non-zero width, instead received width of ' . $width);
            }

            // Break up a JustifierLine of all text until each piece is smaller or equal to $width
            $lines = array(JustifierLine::fromText($this->text));
            $count = 0;
            $newLine = $lines[0]->breakAtColumn($width);

            while($newLine !== null) {
                $lines[] = $newLine;
                $newLine = $lines[++$count]->breakAtColumn($width);
            }
        } else {
            $lines = $this->text;

            // Allow for fluid width (uses longest line with single space)
            if($width == NULL) {
                $width = -1;

                foreach($lines as $line) {
                    // Width of line = Sum of the lengths of the words and the spaces (number of words - 1)
                    $newWidth = $line->calculateWordsLength() + $line->countWords() - 1;

                    if($newWidth > $width) { // Looking for the longest line
                        $width = $newWidth;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Justify each element of array (PHP 5.4 ONLY)
        //$output = array_map(function($line) use ($width) {
        //  return $this->justify($line, $width);
        //}, $lines);

                    // Support for PHP 5.3
                    $output = array();
                    foreach($lines as $line) {
                        $output = $this->justify($line, $width);
                    }

        // If a single-line is passed in, a single line is returned
        if(count($output)) {
            return $output[0];
        }

        return $output;
    }

    private function justify(JustifierLine $line, $width) {
        // Retrieve already calculated line information
        $words     = $line->extractWords();
        $spaces    = $line->countWords() - 1;
        $wordLens  = $line->findWordLengths();
        $wordsLen  = $line->calculateWordsLength();
        $minWidth  = $wordsLen + $spaces;
        $output    = '';

        if($minWidth > $width) {
            throw new LengthException('A minimum width of ' . $minWidth . ' was required, but a width of ' . $width . ' was given instead');
        }

        // No spaces means only one word (center align)
        if($spaces == 0) {
            return str_pad($words[0], $width, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
        }

        for(;$spaces > 0; $spaces--) {
            // Add next word to output and subtract its length from counters
            $output   .= array_shift($words);
            $length    = array_shift($wordLens);
            $wordsLen -= $length;
            $width    -= $length;

            if($spaces == 1) { // Last Iteration
                return $output . str_repeat(' ', $width - $wordsLen) . $words[0];
            }

            // Magic padding is really just simple math
            $padding  = floor(($width - $wordsLen) / $spaces);
            $output  .= str_repeat(' ', $padding);
            $width   -= $padding;
        }
    }
}

class JustifierLine {
    private $words;
    private $numWords;
    private $wordLengths;
    private $wordsLength;

    public static function fromText($text) {
        // Split words into an array
        preg_match_all('/[^ ]+/', $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $words       = $matches[0];

        // Count words
        $numWords    = count($words);

        // Find the length of each word
        $wordLengths = array_map('strlen', $words);

        //And Finally, calculate the total length of all words
        $wordsLength = array_reduce($wordLengths, function($result, $length) {
            return $result + $length;
        }, 0);

        return new JustifierLine($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength);
    }

    private function __construct($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength) {
        $this->words       = $words;
        $this->numWords    = $numWords;
        $this->wordLengths = $wordLengths;
        $this->wordsLength = $wordsLength;
    }

    public function extractWords() { return $this->words; }
    public function countWords() { return $this->numWords; }
    public function findWordLengths() { return $this->wordLengths; }
    public function calculateWordsLength() { return $this->wordsLength; }

    public function breakAtColumn($column) {
        // Avoid extraneous processing if we can determine no breaking can be done
        if($column >= ($this->wordsLength + $this->numWords - 1)) {
            return null;
        }

        $width       = 0;
        $wordsLength = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numWords; $i++) {
            // Add width of next word
            $width += $this->wordLengths[$i];

            // If the line is overflowing past required $width
            if($width > $column) {
                // Remove overflow at end & create a new object with the overflow
                $words             = array_splice($this->words, $i);
                $numWords          = $this->numWords - $i;
                $this->numWords    = $i;
                $wordLengths       = array_splice($this->wordLengths, $i);
                $tempWordsLength   = $wordsLength;
                $wordsLength       = $this->wordsLength - $wordsLength;
                $this->wordsLength = $tempWordsLength;

                return new JustifierLine($words, $numWords, $wordLengths, $wordsLength);
            }

            $width++; // Assuming smallest spacing to fit

            // We also have to keep track of the total $wordsLength
            $wordsLength += $this->wordLengths[$i];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

## Demos

### Original Question (Justifying Lines of Text to width = 48)

You can pass in an array of many strings or just one string to `Justifier`. Calling `Justifier::format($desired_length)` will <del>always</del> return an array of justified lines **if an array of strings or string that required segmentation was passed to the constructor. Otherwise, a string will be returned.* ([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/96gStD))

```
$jus = new Justifier(array(
    'hello world there ok then',
    'hello',
    'ok then',
    'two words',
    'three ok words',
    '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
));

print_r( $jus->format(48) );
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello      world       there       ok       then
    [1] =>                      hello                      
    [2] => ok                                          then
    [3] => two                                        words
    [4] => three                  ok                  words
    [5] => 1    2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
)
```

You may notice I omitted one of the OP's test lines. This is because it was 54 characters and would exceed the `$desired_length` passed to `Justifier::format()`. The function will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for widths that aren't positive, non-zero numbers that exceed or equal to the minimum width. The minimum width is calculated by finding the longest line (of all the lines passed to the constructor) with single spacing.

### Fluid Width Justifying With An Array of Strings

If you omit the width, `Justifier` will use the width of the longest line (of those passed to the constructor) when single spaced. This is the same calculation as finding the minimum width in the previous demo. ([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VnuXK9))

```
$jus = new Justifier(array(
    'hello world there ok then',
    'hello',
    'ok then',
    'this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think',
    'two words',
    'three ok words',
    '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
));

print_r( $jus->format() );
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello        world        there        ok         then
    [1] =>                         hello                         
    [2] => ok                                                then
    [3] => this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think
    [4] => two                                              words
    [5] => three                     ok                     words
    [6] => 1     2     3     4      5      6      7      8      9
)
```

### Justifying a Single String of Text (width = 48)

I've also included a feature in the class which allows you to pass a single, non-broken string to the constructor. This string can be of any length. When you call `Justifier::format($desired_length)` the string is broken into lines such that each line is filled with as much text as possible and justified before starting a new line. The class will complain with an `InvalidArgumentException` because you must provide a width into which it can break the string. If anyone can think of a sensible default or way to programmatically determine a default for a string, I'm completely open to suggestions. ([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HCS2AA))

```
$jus = new Justifier(
    'hello world there ok then hello ok then this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think two words three ok words 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
);

print_r( $jus->format(48) );
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello world there ok then  hello  ok  then  this
    [1] => string is almost  certainly  longer  than  48  I
    [2] => think two words three ok words 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
)
```

Comment: *troll mode on*. OP asked for a function, not a huge class.

Comment: @Alex If you would have actually glanced at the code before you trolled, you would have noticed that there are two classes, one of which could be dropped into many other monospaced text formatters. *reusability mode on.*

Comment: *troll mode still on* do you actually think there are many *monospaced text formatters*? Sorry for these questions, but I still don't see any practical reason to use object-oriented approach here.

Comment: @Alex I count eleven on this page. And gist of many of the algorithms can be used in word processing to justify text. Instead of counting number of characters, they would just need to count the width of the characters (which in my OOP case would only require slight modifications to the second class instead of a complete overhaul).

Comment: I meant _different monospaced text formatters_. Designed to deal with different tasks. And why do you consider object-oriented solution to be more reusable than functional one? As i see, you just took a functional approach and made some private properties (which could easily be presented as arguments). OOP is great when there is a *real need* in it. When I look at your demo code, I keep asking myself - who is that Justifier? What it does, and why he takes a string as an input? How to use it? Why an _object_ should do it?

Comment: @Alex If the object oriented approach isn't one you would take, the purpose of my post wasn't to convince you otherwise. My code works. That was the purpose. If you want to write a functional solution, be my guest. I wouldn't question the functional approach on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bit different implementation just towards the end.

```
<?php
function justify($str, $to_len) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $strlen = strlen($str);

    if($str == '') return '';

    if($strlen >= $to_len) {
        return substr($str, 0, $to_len);   
    }

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $word_count = count($words);
    $space_count = $word_count - 1;

    if($word_count == 1) {
        return str_pad($str, $to_len, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
    }

    $space = $to_len - $strlen + $space_count;
    $per_space = floor($space/$space_count);
    $spaces = str_pad('', $per_space, ' ');
    $curr_word = implode($words, $spaces);
    while(strlen($curr_word) < $to_len){
    $curr_word = substr($curr_word,0,preg_match("[! ][".$spaces."][! ]",$curr_word))." ".preg_match("[! ][".$spaces."][! ]",$curr_word));
    }
    return $curr_word;

?>
```

I'm not sure about the `regexp`, I just meant `$spaces` and not next space.

Comment: This solution violates the requirement that the distribution of the amount of spaces does not vary by more than 1. For 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, your function outputs 1___________2____3____4____5____6____7____8____9

Comment: the regexp may not be clear, I meant check for exactly $spaces and not another space more. So once it adds a " " to one space the next preg_match  gets the next space.

Comment: Edit: Now it checks for $spaces not bordered by other spaces. so it matches uniquely each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.  For what it's worth, it took me about 20 minutes to make both the justify function and acceptance tests for it; 5 of those minutes debugging the justify function.  Also, I used notpad++ instead of a more robust IDE to try to simulate to some extent the interview environment.

I think this might be too large of a problem for a whiteboard interview question, unless the interviewer lets you write in pseudocode and is more interested in your thought process that what you are putting on the board.

```
<?php


function justify($str_in, $desired_length) {
    $words = preg_split("/ +/",$str_in);
    // handle special cases
    if(count($words)==0) { return str_repeat(" ",$desired_length); }

    // turn single word case into a normal case
    if(count($words)==1) { $words = array("",$words[0],""); }

    $numwords = count($words);
    $wordlength = strlen(join("",$words));
    // handles cases where words are longer than the desired_length
    if($wordlength>($desired_length-$numwords)) { 
        return substr(join(" ",$words),0,$desired_length);
    }

    $minspace = floor(($desired_length-$wordlength)/($numwords-1));
    $extraspace = $desired_length - $wordlength - ($minspace * ($numwords-1));
    $result = $words[0];
    for($i=1;$i<$numwords;$i++) {
        if($extraspace>0) {
            $result.=" ";
            $extraspace--;
        }
        $result.=str_repeat(" ",$minspace);
        $result.=$words[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}

function acceptance_justify($orig_str, $just_str, $expected_length) {
    // should be the correct length
    if(strlen($just_str)!=$expected_length) { return false; }

    // should contain most of the words in the original string, in the right order
    if(preg_replace("/ +/","",substr($orig_str,0,$expected_length)) != preg_replace("/ +/","",substr($just_str,0,$expected_length))) { return false; }

    //spacing should be uniform (+/- 1 space)
    if(!preg_match("/( +)/",$just_str,$spaces)) { return false; }

    $space_length=strlen($spaces[0]);
    $smin=$space_length;
    $smax=$space_length;
    for($i=1;$i<count(@spaces);$i++) {
        $smin=min($smin,strlen($spaces));
        $smax=max($smax,strlen($spaces));
    }
    if(($smax-$smin)>1) { return false; }
    return true;
}

function run_test($str,$len) {
    print "<pre>";
    print "$str  ==> \n";
    $result = justify($str,$len);
    print preg_replace("/ /",".",$result) . "\n";
    print acceptance_justify($str,$result,$len)?"passed":"FAILED";
    print "\n\n</pre>";
}


run_test("hello world there ok then",48);
run_test("hello",48);
run_test("this string is almost certainly longer than 48 I think",48);
run_test("two words",48);
run_test("three ok words",48);
run_test("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9",48);
```