# Stretching a string to number of characters [Python]

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say a have list/string that looks like this - `a = 'erik ffffffffff f f f f f '`.
By `b = a.split()`, I can get a list with the specific "words". The total number of characters in this list is `sum([len(i) for i in b])`, which is 19.

Now, I am quite stuck at efficiently coming up with a way of how to stretch this list so the resulting string is "justified" to a certain width by inserting white spaces between the words. Let's say that the required width is 30. The result then should be something like `c = 'erik  ffffffffff  f  f  f  f f'`, simply a string justified to a number characters (width), like in Word for example.

My thinking was along the following way (not working):

```
a = 'erik ffffffffff f f f f f '
width = 30
b = a.split()
c = b.copy()
print(b)

spaces = width - sum([len(i) for i in b])
for i, item in cycle(enumerate(c)):
    print(i, item)
    if spaces == 0:
        break
    c[i] = item + ' '
    spaces -= 1
    print(spaces)

print(c)
sum([len(i) for i in c])
```

Comment: Here is an hint in PHP : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058483/justify-string-algorithm

Comment: @Jona Thanks for that but the implementations there go a bit further. For example, I know that the string itself is shorter than 30 characters. So it's a simple matter of inserting white spaces, which I, somehow, can't manage to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can make us of the [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) optional argument `count`, which replaces the first x number of occurrences (maximum!). This is why you loop it in a `while` and recalculate the difference until you have reached the desired width. Here's an example.

```
a = 'erik ffffffffff f f f f f '
width = 50

b=a.strip()  #remove leading and trailing whitespace
diff=width-len(b)
while diff > 0:
    b=b.replace(' ','  ',diff)
    diff = width - len(b)

print(b)
print(len(b))
```

**Output:**

```
erik        ffffffffff       f    f    f    f    f
50
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a more efficient solution. However, I also need to string to end with a word, not with a blank space. (It's not yet incorporated in my code).

Comment: Ok, a bit more thinking on my side was required. Simple strip() on the first string does the job.

Comment: Somehow, this solution does not work anymore for me when the lines are shorter than 20 characters. It gets stuck in the while loop. Do you reckon where the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want the gaps to differ by more than one space:

```
a = 'erik ffffffffff f f f f f '
width = 35

def stretch(line, width):
    line = line.strip()
    if " " in line:
        diff = width - len(line)
        gap = " "
        while diff > 0:
            line = line.replace(gap, gap+" ", diff)
            diff = width - len(line)
            gap += " "
    return line

print(stretch(a, width))
```

**Output:**

```
erik   ffffffffff   f   f   f  f  f
```